# DNS: Using a stub zone instead of delegation for child domains: which pros and cons?

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2019

I’m making some experiments using VMWare Workstation Pro 16; I have put on a network with five computers as you can see in the below picture:
[image]

This is not an Active Directory environment, there is not a DHCP server and each computer has its manual ip address configuration.

- **R0** is a Windows Server 2019 Std configured as a router;
- **SRV1** and **SRV2** are both Windows Server 2019 Std configured as DNS servers;
- the two laptops in the picture are Windows 10 Pro machines called **PC-1** and **PC-2**

This is what I have done:

1. I created a primary forward zone for ALPHA.TEST on SRV1
2. I created a primary forward zone for NORTH.ALPHA.TEST on SRV2
3. I created a stub zone on SRV1 for NORTH.ALPHA.TEST
4. I created a stub zone on SRV2 for ALPHA.TEST
5. I populated both domains with some records

Everything works like a charm: computers can resolve names on ALPHA.TEST and NORTH.ALPHA.TEST

It seems that I created a delegation but using a stub zone instead of the specific delegation procedure.

Which are the differences (pros and cons) between what I’ve done, using stub zones, and the use of the specific delegation procedure for delegating subdomains?